# Spring Data JPA incomprehensible logic of work

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

In service I have this method:

```
@Transactional
public void CatalogRequest(CatalogDto catalogDto) {

  updateCatalog(catalogDto);

}
```

in this method with `@Transactional` annotation I cal internal private method

```
private void updateCatalog(CatalogDto catalogDto) {
    Catalog catalog = catalogsRepository.findByGuigAndIsActive(catalogDto.getGuid(), true);

    if (catalog != null) {
      catalog.setIsActive(false);
      catalogsRepository.save(catalog);
    }

    CatalogMapper catalogMapper = new CatalogMapper(catalogDto);

    Catalog newCatalog = catalogMapper.toDomain();
    catalogsRepository.save(newCatalog);
  }
```

In my case I have catalog active and I wait next logic:

1. `catalogsRepository.findByGuigAndIsActive` find active catalog
2. `if (catalog != null)` - true
3. I set active `false` and save catalog

   ```
   catalog.setIsActive(false);
   catalogsRepository.save(catalog);
   ```
4. create new catalog from dto and save it with active true status.

But I get `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` because I have constraint:

```
create unique index CATALOG_UN1
    on CATALOGS (CASE "IS_ACTIVE" WHEN 1 THEN "GUIG" WHEN 0 THEN NULL END)
```

I'm waiting for that old catalog change status to not active, update, and new catalog insert with active status. And it in transaction

```
begin transaction
oldCatalog.setActive(true)
update oldCatalog
create new catalog with active true
insert new catalog
commit
```

But it looks like that the transaction works somehow differently or I do not understand something. When I try insert new catalog with active status JPA think that old active status true too and throw `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`. I fix this  like this:

```
if (catalog != null) {
    catalog.setIsActive(false);
    catalogsRepository.saveAndFlush(catalog);
}
```

But I do not understand whether I'm doing the right thing and why simple `save()` not worked.

Answer (score 2):

When you save a `Managed Entity`, which means you are updating an entity that `Hibernate` fetched from database, `Hibernate` doesn't send update query to the database until it tries to commit the `Transaction`. so in your case, if you don't force `Hibernate` to send the update query first, your create query will be sent to the database before update query and database will find a constraint violation. That's why the `JDBC Driver` throws an exception.

But when you use `saveAndFlush`, you force the `Hibernate` to send all the queries that has been cached in it's buffer to the database, so when you save your new entity, the create query will be sent to database after update query.

Comment: if I insert a new record, I will receive an error, the transaction will roll back my update saveAndFlush?

Comment: What exception do you get ? can you send the error you get from database?